# Can anyone having GAE Spring BOOT app deployed successful in CLOUD

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, spring-boot

The Spring boot app is not working after deployed through GAE to cloud. Is any one having success with spring boot on GAE? *google app engine(GAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot ?

**TL;DR**
Copy pasting the read me file from the above link

## Spring Boot based Hello World app

This sample shows how to run a [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) application on [Google
Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/java/). It uses the [Google App Engine flexible
environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).

### Before you begin

This sample assumes you have [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/) installed.

#### Download Maven

These samples use the [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org) build system. Before getting
started, be sure to [download](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and [install](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) it.
When you use Maven as described here, it will automatically download the needed
client libraries.

#### Create a Project in the Google Cloud Platform Console

If you haven't already created a project, create one now. Projects enable you to
manage all Google Cloud Platform resources for your app, including deployment,
access control, billing, and services.

1. Open the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. In the drop-down menu at the top, select **Create a project**.
3. Give your project a name.
4. Make a note of the project ID, which might be different from the project
   name. The project ID is used in commands and in configurations.

#### Enable billing for your project.

If you haven't already enabled billing for your project, [enable
billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/settings) now.  Enabling billing allows the application to
consume billable resources such as running instances and storing data.

#### Install the Google Cloud SDK.

If you haven't already installed the Google Cloud SDK, [install and initialize
the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) now. The SDK contains tools and libraries that
enable you to create and manage resources on Google Cloud Platform.

#### Install the Google App Engine SDK for Java

`gcloud components update app-engine-java
gcloud components update`

### Run the application locally

1. Set the correct Cloud SDK project via `gcloud config set project
   YOUR_PROJECT` to the ID of your application.
2. Run `mvn spring-boot:run`
3. Visit http://localhost:8080

### Deploy to App Engine flexible environment

1. `mvn gcloud:deploy`
2. Visit `http://YOUR_PROJECT.appspot.com`.

Java is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.